# Player game object vanishes on play

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, gameobject

So im trying to put a game object into my game using the robot boy prefab from the standard assets on the asset store.

However, although he shows in the game view after putting him into the scene, as soon as I try to play the game he vanishes. Ive got the sorting layers etc right as far as I can see. Not sure why this is happening?

See attached for examples

[image]

Comment: Is the Allen gameobject still in the hierarchy when the game is running? Might give you a clue as to whats happening.

Comment: yes its still present. It just doesnt render the graphics and is invisible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the player GameObject in hierarchy while in playmode and go to scene view and press F key twice to see where it is hiding. If you can locate it within your level setup Most probably it is hiden behind something because of sorting layer. Change the sorting layer for player to bring it front.

It might not be unvisible due to sorting layer because there is a case when rigidbody plays weird and teleports player to far away from the camera. Or it might be constantly falling down because of improper collider configuration. Check its transform component specially position if it is constantly changing or ifs different than what you had before playing the game. And check the scale as well. It might be set to (0,0,0) and the player is appearing invisible

Hope this helps.

Comment: looking into it further, it appears to be there and the rigid body is working as it is staying on the platform. However ive noticed that the sprite is missing on play, and it wont let me put another in it

Comment: What does it say when you try to assign the sprite? can you add a screenshot of player inspector in play mode.

Comment: heres the screen grab: https://ibb.co/kJRmrQ  when I try and drag and drop a new sprite over it, it hightlights blue to but when i let go it doesnt update it

Comment: Is any of the script accessing sprite renderer of player?

Comment: @UmairM The problem is the animator attached to that GameObject. Ask OP to remove that and see what happens. It looks like the animator is modifying the sprite. Either that or `spriteRenderer.sprite` is being modified by OP somewhere in the code.

Comment: that was exactly the issue. ive unticked the animator and its now showing. thanks :)